# how to update pymongo from version 2.7 to 3.6

Tags: python, pymongo

I run the command `pip freeze | grep "pymongo"` in my Mac OS ,it show the version `pymongo==2.7.2`

I want to update my pymongo from version 2.7 to 3.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow the below steps,

1. First download the zip file from https://pypi.org/simple/pymongo/ as
   what version you want (I download the latest version 3.6.1).
2. Move to the download folder.
3. Unzip the folder using command

   ```
   tar -xzf pymongo-3.6.1.tar.gz
   ```
4. Install the python-3.6.1

   ```
   sudo python -m pip install ../../Downloads/pymongo-3.6.1
   ```

Answer (score 2):

Does this work?

`pip install pymongo --upgrade`

Comment: It gives the following output ,

Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/pymongo/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION] tlsv1 alert protocol version (_ssl.c:590) - skipping
Requirement already up-to-date: pymongo in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages